# Groupby columns on ID and month and assign value for each month as new colmuns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where i groupby the monthly data with the same id:

```
temp1 = listvar[2].groupby(["id", "month"])["value"].mean()
```

This results in this:

```
id       month

SN10380  1       -9.670370
         2       -8.303571
         3       -4.932143
         4        0.475862
         5        5.732000
                    ...   
SN99950  8        6.326786
         9        4.623529
         10       1.290566
         11      -0.867273
         12      -2.485455
```

I then want to have each month and the corresponding value as a own column on the same ID, like this:

```
  id         month_1     month_2  month_3   month_4 .... month_12

  SN10380   -9.670370   -8.303571 .....

  SN99950
```

I have tried different solutions using apply(), transform() and agg(), but aren't able to produce the wanted output.

Comment: try ```pivot```

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks, worked like a charm! What an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unstack`. Here's the sample code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "month": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "value": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
})

temp1 = df.groupby(["id", "month"])["value"].mean()

temp1.unstack()
```

I hope it helps!